# Django form, use data in field from other model

Tags: python, django

How to fill field in form based on model `id`?

I have to models, `Match` and `MatchRegister`.
Logged-in user can register for `Match`, the data is written in `MatchRegister`.

I am now creating form for editing `Match` objects and want to populate fields `referee_a` and `referee_b` values from `MatchRegister` table (for edited match of course).

I don't know how to to do this exaclty. Could you please help me with it?

```
class MatchForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = (
            'match_number', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'match_category',
            'date_time', 'notes', 'referee_a', 'referee_b')
        widgets = {
            'match_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'home_team': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'away_team': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'match_category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'date_time': forms.DateTimeField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'referee_a': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            'referee_b': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            'notes': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }

class MatchRegister(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(
        Match,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    ref_reg = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )


class Match(models.Model):

    match_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,

    )
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='home_team',

    )
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='away_team',

    )
    match_category = models.ForeignKey(
        MatchCategory,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,

    )
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,

    )
    notes = models.TextField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=True,

    )
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=timezone.now
    )

    referee_a = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='referee_a',

    )

    referee_b = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='referee_b',

    )
```

Comment: could you please show the rest of your model so we can understand where referee_a and referee_b comes from (and how it is defined)?

Comment: Yes, I have edited main post. You can see it now